# Getting back same row twice on left join

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query to find if a product has a quantity greater then 0 and if its date meets a certain parameter. Those results are ran through a while loop to be listed on a page. The problem I am running into is that it selects the same ID twice from each table because of my parameters...that leads to the item being displayed twice. I don't want that of course.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `trade_show_inventory` 
    LEFT JOIN `trade_show_reserved` 
    ON `trade_show_inventory`.`ID` = `trade_show_reserved`.`ProductID` 
    WHERE `trade_show_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0  
    OR `trade_show_reserved`.`DateReserved` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-31' 
    ORDER BY `trade_show_inventory`.`ProductName`
```

My results from the query are below in the image if I have the same product checked out twice by a user with a quantity of 1 and 1. Look at ID 6 and you will see the results. What I would like the results to be, is that I want to be able to query all of the dates from DateReserved and at the same time check for quantities greater then 0..at the same time do not display the same product twice. The DateReserved is coming from a different table as opposed to the ID that is highlighted in the picture. How would I achieve this result? Do I need to do something in my while loop? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here is my while loop.

```
        while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $results['ProductName'];
        echo
        "<li>
            <img style='width: 200px; height: 200px' src='images/inventory/" . $results['Image'] . "'/>" . 
            "<div class='infoContainer'>" .
            "<a class='productLink' href='/ts/selectItems.php?status=active&id=" . $results['ID'] . "'>" . $results['ProductName'] . "</a>" . 
            "<br />" . 
            "<i>Currently Available </i>" . 
            "<i class='quantity'>" . $results['Quantity'] . "</i>" . 
            "</div>" .
        "</li>";
    }
```

[image: Results from query]

Comment: wording says `quantity greater then 0 AND if its date meets a certain parameter` query says `OR`

Comment: It looks like RID is different therefore not the same row. If you have two matching rows in the child table, you will get two rows.

Comment: So, iGanja change the name of the row eh?

Comment: Use DISTINCT and remove that column from the result set. SELECT * is not recommended anyway.

Comment: You could also save the ID in your where loop then skip subsequent records with the same ID.

Comment: Yeah, but if I skip over the ID the DateReserved field will not be searched.

Comment: I just want to search my DateReserved field and make sure quantities are greater then 0 while listing these.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [just the columns you need] 
    FROM `trade_show_inventory` 
    LEFT JOIN `trade_show_reserved` 
    ON `trade_show_inventory`.`ID` = `trade_show_reserved`.`ProductID` 
    WHERE `trade_show_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0  
    OR `trade_show_reserved`.`DateReserved` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-31' 
    ORDER BY `trade_show_inventory`.`ProductName`
    GROUP BY [just the columns you need]
```

If you remove the RID column from this, the GROUP BY will eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Hold on one second.